# Regex for groovy not working

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Please find below my code. I am trying to iterate through files and in a directory and print out all the match to the regex: `(&)(.+?\b)`
however this doesn't seem to work (it returns an empty string). Where did I go wrong?

```
import groovy.io.FileType

class FileExample {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        def list = []

        def dir = new File("*path to dir*")
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
            list << file.name;
            def s= "${file.text}";
            def w = s.toString();
            w.readLines().grep(~/(&)(.+?\b)/)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect as the outcome of this?  I'd assume, that you want the files containing lines matching the regexp?  `Each` is always for side effects and returns at best its input.

Comment: I want all the regex matches to be listed, I don't really care about the location of the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
import groovy.io.FileType
class FileExample {
   static void main(String[] args) {

        def list = []
        def dir = new File("/path/to/directory/containingfiles")
        def p = []
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { 
            file -> list << file.name
            def s = file.text
            def findtp = (s =~ /(&)(.+?\b)/)
            findtp.each {
                p.push(it[2])
                // As I'm only interested in the second matched group
            }
        }
        p.each { 
            println it
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, all the matched strings are stored in the array p and can be printed/used elsewhere by p[0] etc.

Answer (score 0):

`w.readLines().grep(~/(&)(.+?\b)/)` does not do any output, it gives you the matching lines as return value, so if you change it to `println w.readLines().grep(~/(&)(.+?\b)/)` or `w.readLines().grep(~/(&)(.+?\b)/).each { println it }`, you will get the matched lines printed on `stdout`.

Btw.

```
 def s= "${file.text}";
 def w = s.toString();
 w.readLines()
```

is just a biiiig waste of time. It is exactly the same as `file.text.readLines()`.

`"${file.text}"` is a `GString` that replaces the placeholders on evaluation,  but as you have nothing but the `file.text` placeholder, this is the same as `file.text as String` or `file.text.toString()`.

But as `file.text` actually is a `String` already, it is identical to `file.text`.

And even if you would need the `GString` because you have more than the placeholder in it, `GString` already has a `readLines()` method, so no need for using `.toString()` first, even if a `GString` would be necessary.